# UITapGestureRecognizer only detects parent view tap

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using UITapGestureRecognizer for detecting which UIView was tapped on my screen but for some reason it only detects the parent view tap, for example below code logs only parent views tag. How do i detect subview taps which are present on main view. Please suggest.

```
Inside View did load :- 

UITapGestureRecognizer *viewTapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(actionForViewTapped:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:viewTapRecognizer];
```

Method outside view did load.

```
-(void) actionForViewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)sender {
    NSLog(@"view tapped");
    UIView *view = sender.view;
    NSLog(@"view tag is %lu", view.tag); //Always prints parent view tag. 

    if(view.tag == 10){
        NSLog(@"tag1 tapped"); //Not called
    }
    if(view.tag == 20){
        NSLog(@"tag 2 tapped"); //Not called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have more options to find detecting on sub view by tap gesture

**CHOICE 1**:Directly tap to SubView

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSubView)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[subView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```

**CHOICE 2**:Finding tap on SubView through Parent View

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapSubView)];
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];


-(void)tapSubView:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
   UIView* view = sender.view;
   CGPoint loc = [sender locationInView:view];
   UIView* subview = [view hitTest:loc withEvent:nil];
               //OR
   CGPoint point = [sender locationInView:sender.view];
   UIView *viewTouched = [sender.view hitTest:point withEvent:nil];

   if ([viewTouched isKindOfClass:[self.view class]])
   {
      NSLog(@"the subView is called");
   } 
   else 
   {
      NSLog(@"the subView is not called");
   }
}
```

Printed Output is

```
the subView is called
```

**CHOICE 3**:Find Tap Detection using Delegate methods of Gesture

First You have to add the **GestureRecognizerDelegate**

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch 
{
  if([touch.view isKindOfClass: [self.view class]] == YES)
  {
    return YES; // return YES (the default) to allow the gesture recognizer to examine the touch object
  }
  else {
    return NO;  //NO to prevent the gesture recognizer from seeing this touch object.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The gesture recognizer is only associated with one specific view, which means it will only recognize touches on the view it is added to. If you want to know which subview was touched, then you will need to do a couple of things:

1. Set `userInteractionEnabled = false` for each subview. This will make it so that every touch on a subview is passed up to the parent view, and the touch will be recognized by the gesture recognizer.
2. There isn't enough information on your view hierarchy or layout to know exactly how to proceed from here, but you can use one or some of these methods to determine which view was touched:  `UIView.hitTest(_:with:)`, `UIView.point(inside:with:)`, `CGRectContainsPoint()` or `UIGestureRecognizer.location(in:)`. For example, if the subviews do not overlap each other, you could use the following code snippet to test if the touch was in a particular view:

   ```
   let location = tapGesture.locationInView(parentView)
   if CGRectContainsPoint(subview1, location) {
       // subview1 was touched
   }
   ```

Comment: This looks complicated and a workaround, is there a other way to add action to tap of UIView, I did try making the view as UIControl but even that doesnt work.

Comment: This is not a workaround. This is how the view/touch system works. Alternatives depend highly on what your view hierarchy looks like. Something being "complicated" should never deter you from exploring it. While I wrote a lot of text to explain what's happening, the actual code I wrote was 3 lines; which is not complicated at all. Exploring this avenue will help you to learn more about how the system works and help you to solve these problems for yourself in the future. You cannot always rely on a one line copy/paste answer from SO.

Comment: I think your right on subviews explanation thanks, but I have added a transparent button on the UIView and an action to it , which works fine.

Comment: Do you want the tap gesture AND the normal button action to fire when the button is pressed?

Comment: Yes. Your right, i wanted to detect one of my view taps and have an action on top of it.

Comment: You could add another action to the button that uses the same method as the gesture action.  `button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionForViewTapped(_:)), forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)`. The `actionForViewTapped(_:)` method's argument and method body would need to be of type `AnyObject` instead of `UITapGestureRecognizer` so that it could accommodate the button and the tap gesture.